# Python - printing out errors

Tags: python, printing

So I have a program that reason a lines file and prints out any errors to stderr. So if I get input that looks like this:

```
line 1 2x 3 4
line 1 2 x3 4
lixe 251 2 3 4 5
line 1 2 3 4
line 251 2 3 4
```

Then the output should look like:

```
Error in line 1:
   line 1 2x 3 4
           ^
Error in line 2:
   line 1 2 x3 4
            ^
Error in line 3:
   lixe 251 2 3 4 5
     ^
Error in line 5:
   line 251 2 3 4
        ^
Error in line 6:
   line 1 2 3 4 5
                ^
```

So here's what I have for error checking:

```
except Exception as e:
    for line in lines_file:
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Error in line ' + str(line_number) + ":"
        print >> sys.stderr, " " * 4 + line,
        print >> sys.stderr, " " * (offset + 4) + "^"
sys.exit(1)
```

But for this code, the output looks like this:

```
Error in line 1:
    line 1 2 x3 4
            ^
Error in line 1:
    lixe 251 2 3 4 5
            ^
Error in line 1:
    line 1 2 3 4
            ^
Error in line 1:
    line 251 2 3 4
            ^
Error in line 1:
    line 1 2 3 4 5
            ^
Error in line 1:
    line 1 2 3 4 x5
            ^
```

And it only shows the one line. So how can I make it print out all the lines? Here's my code with the try bock:

```
for line in lines_file:
    line_number = 1
    #get offset up to start of coordinates
    start = re.compile('\s*line\s*')
    m = start.match(line)
    offset = m.end()

    try:
        for i in range(4):
            xy = re.compile('\s*([-]?[0-9]{1,3})\s*')

            if xy.match(line,offset):
                m = xy.match(line,offset)
            else:
                raise Exception

            coordinate = m.group(1)

            if int(coordinate) > 250 or int(coordinate) < -250:
                raise Exception

            offset = m.end()

        end = re.compile('\s*$')
        if not end.match(line,offset):
            raise Exception

    except Exception as e:
        for line in lines_file:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Error in line ' + str(line_number) + ":"
            print >> sys.stderr, " " * 4 + line,
            print >> sys.stderr, " " * (offset + 4) + "^"
    sys.exit(1)

    line_number += 1
    offset = 0

    p = re.compile('line\s*([-]?[0-9]{1,3})\s*([-]?[0-9]{1,3})\s*([-]?[0-9]{1,3})\s*([-]?[0-9]{1,3})')
    m = p.match(line)
    x0 = int(m.group(1))
    y0 = int(m.group(2))
    x1 = int(m.group(3))
    y1 = int(m.group(4))

    print str(x0), str(y0), str(x1), str(y1)
```

Comment: you need to write a loop to print everything

Comment: what kind of loop. Is it a for each loop where you go "for x in line"?

Comment: Ok I updated my code to show more of my program.

Comment: Updated my code again with my attempt at looping through all the line errors but I still can't get the correct output.

Comment: Just updated my code again. There's now more than just one line but the actual lines are not in order.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves the problem, but two things pop out when looking at your code...

(1) The `except` block in not indented with the `try` block.

(2) As a consequence, the `line_number` and `offset` variables never seem to be updated.

If you put the `except` block at the level of `try`, then the code under `except` would be executed every time you find an exception, and you would not need to add a second `for line ...` loop within it.

Comment: It actually was indented correctly with the try block but I guess it got automatically formatted when I pasted the code here.

Comment: I see---thanks for fixing it. One question: Why do you need to loop through the lines when you see an exception? After it has been caught, it should simply print that one line....